# Custom dashboard page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a client project now,its on Wordpress .I need to do following things

1.Each logged user should redirect to a custom dashboard page(Not usual Wordpress dashboard).

2.Each logged user able to upload the PDF from Dashboard and store them.

Right now I am kinda struck like where to start,I have login system,registration and profile page implemented using User Profile Plugin from codecanyon.

Someone please advise me to implement the Custom Dashboard for each logged user,
How to upload the PDF for each user and how to store them?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know hows your codecanyon scirpts working, but the scenario to achieve this is:

1. Make Custom PostType/Custom Template that only works with logged-in users, Or you can check if detect the logged in user's session on that particular dashboard so that other users can't access it.
2. Make custom login form and after success logged in, redirect the logged in user to that particular PostType/Template that you make for logged in users.
3. I don't think the default WordPress upload works in front, so you have to create a custom upload scripts that upload the pdf files and store the credential of the user in wp_options table, with `update_option()`

This thread helps you to use default wordpress media uploader in front end [Front End Media Uploading in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160979/front-end-media-uploading-in-wordpress)