# Front End Upload Images Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, meta

The below code is successfully creating a custom post and adding meta details to it. The code is also dumping uploading images into an uploads folder in the site root. I'm stuck on creating a foreach argument to post the image file paths into the following custom fields as text strings: image_1, image_2, image_3 and image_4.

```
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

                require('../wp-load.php'); 

                $a = $_POST['a'];
                $b = $_POST['b'];
                $c = $_POST['c'];
                $d = $_POST['d'];
                $e = $_POST['e'];

                include('../src/class.fileuploader.php');

                $FileUploader = new FileUploader('files', array(
                    'uploadDir' => '../uploads/',
                    'title' => 'name'
                ));

                $data = $FileUploader->upload();

                if($data['isSuccess'] && count($data['files']) > 0) {

                    $uploadedFiles = $data['files'];
                }
                if($data['hasWarnings']) {
                    $warnings = $data['warnings'];

                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($warnings);
                    echo '</pre>';
                    exit;
                }

                foreach($FileUploader->getRemovedFiles('file') as $key=>$value) {
                    unlink('../uploads/' . $value['name']);
                }

                $my_post = array(
                    'ID' => '',
                    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['a']),
                    'post_content'  => $_POST['d'],
                    'post_status'   => 'draft',
                    'post_type'     => 'custompost'
                );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);


                add_post_meta($post_id, 'b', $b, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'c', $c, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'e', $e, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'image_1', $image_1, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'image_2', $image_2, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'image_3', $image_3, true);
                add_post_meta($post_id, 'image_4', $image_4, true);

            header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank-you/');

            } else {

            header('Location: http://www.example.com/thank-you/');

            }

            ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Front End Media Uploading in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160979/front-end-media-uploading-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(isset($_POST['pj'])){
        global $wpdb;
            $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
            foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
                if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
                }
                  if ($files['name'][$key]) {
                        $file = array(
                          'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                          'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                          'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                          'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                          'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
                        );

                        $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                        $movefile =  wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides );
                        if ( $movefile && !isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) { 
                                //echo $movefile['url'];
add_post_meta($postid , 'images' , $movefile['url']);
                        }

                  }
            }


    }
```

Replace 'upload_attachment' from your input type file name .

$files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];

and you can upload your image into post meta using this code

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with some on page jQuery. Thanks for your help though.